# Reflection with Delegates

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I'm using reflection to compare two list of objects(of same type) and collecting the list of properties which have different values. I may iterate through lots of object list to compare which ended in performance lag. I came to know about using delegates in the reflection so we can bypass the `.GetValue(obj, null)` which is taking time. The types of my class properties is wide. It can be string, int and enum. The available solutions are not working out for me. Thanks for your help.

The code I'm using to compare the 2 objects of same type

```
public List<string> Compare<T>(object A, object B)
{
                var type = typeof(T);
                var allProperties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                List<string> unequalProperties =
                    (
                        from pi in allProperties 
                        let AValue = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(A, null)
                        let BValue = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(B, null)
                        where AValue != BValue && (AValue == null || !AValue.Equals(BValue))
                        select pi.Name
                    ).ToList();
                return unequalProperties;
}
```

The two `.GetValue(A/B, null)` is producing the lag which i want to skip using delegates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cache the getter delegates in a static field, by putting your code into a generic class.

You can then cache the properties themselves using a two-level class hierarchy using some more generics.

```cs
public List<string> Compare<T>(T A, T B)
{
    return GenericComparer<T>.Compare(A, B);
}

abstract class PropertyCompareBase<T>
{
    public string Name;
    public abstract bool CompareProperty(T A, T B);
}

class PropertyCompare<T, TProperty> : PropertyCompareBase<T>
{
    Func<T, TProperty> Getter;

    public PropertyCompare(PropertyInfo prop)
    {
        Name = prop.Name;
        Getter = (Func<T, TProperty>)prop.GetMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, TProperty>));
    }

    public override bool CompareProperty(T A, T B)
    {
        return EqualityComparer<TProperty>.Default.Equals(Getter(A), Getter(B));
    }
}

static class GenericComparer<T>
{
    static List<PropertyCompareBase<T>> properties = typeof(T)
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
        .Select(p => (PropertyCompareBase<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(
                         typeof(PropertyCompare<,>)
                         .MakeGenericType(typeof(T), p.PropertyType),
                        p))
        .ToList();

    static public List<string> Compare(T A, T B)
    {
        List<string> unequalProperties =
            properties.Where(p => !p.CompareProperty(A, B))
                      .Select(p => p.Name)
                      .ToList();
        return unequalProperties;
    }
}
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f6BhKj)

Comment: Hello Charlieface, Thank you so much for this answer. I tried it as it is and it works really faster. One more quick thing is, I need to have the values of the comparing properties, not only the name of the properties. I agree that my example code is returning only name list and that's just to explain you people. Is that possible to return the list of objects with name, valueA and valueB ?

Comment: They could be different types, do you just want to stringify them? You could change the property compare function to return a tuple `public override (bool, string, string) CompareProperty(T A, T B) { var a = Getter(A); var b = Getter(B); return (EqualityComparer<TProperty>.Default.Equals(a, b), a, b); }` then you can change the main compare function `properties.Select(p => p.CompareProperty(A, B)).Where(result => !result.Item1).ToList()`

Comment: Great, I have already modified the Property Compare method to return my List<CustomObject> witht the prop name and values of A and B objects and other stuffs. Thanks a lot again for the performance enhancement. Can you please share us some resource where we can learn this caching of delegates from basics if possible?

Comment: This is a good start https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/ I'm just making heavy use of nested generics so that all the reflection is cached, even though we don't know the types of the properties